# How to include a json-rpc in the pow consensus building on Substrate?

Tags: json-rpc, pow, consensus, substrate

In the pow consensus module of substrate, the miner does not dig ore by means of RPC access, how to access?

I don't have idea.

```
fn mine(
        &self,
        parent: &BlockId<B>,
        pre_hash: &H256,
        difficulty: Difficulty,
        round: u32,
    ) -> Result<Option<RawSeal>, String> {
        let mut rng = SmallRng::from_rng(&mut thread_rng())
            .map_err(|e| format!("Initialize RNG failed for mining: {:?}", e))?;
        let key_hash = key_hash(self.client.as_ref(), parent)?;

        for _ in 0..round {
            let nonce = H256::random_using(&mut rng);

            let compute = Compute {
                key_hash,
                difficulty,
                pre_hash: *pre_hash,
                nonce,
            };

            let seal = compute.compute();

            if is_valid_hash(&seal.work, difficulty) {
                return Ok(Some(seal.encode()))
            }
        }
        Ok(None)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you follow a pattern similar to [Kulupu](https://github.com/kulupu/kulupu/) for creating a PoW Substrate blockchain.

In Kulupu, it seems the Substrate service starts mining if it detects your are an "authority":

```rust
/// Builds a new service for a full client.
pub fn new_full<C: Send + Default + 'static>(config: Configuration<C, GenesisConfig>, author: Option<&str>, threads: usize, round: u32)
    -> Result<impl AbstractService, ServiceError>
{
    let is_authority = config.roles.is_authority();

    let (builder, inherent_data_providers) = new_full_start!(config, author);

    let service = builder
        .with_network_protocol(|_| Ok(NodeProtocol::new()))?
        .with_finality_proof_provider(|_client, _backend| {
            Ok(Arc::new(()) as _)
        })?
        .build()?;

    if is_authority {
        for _ in 0..threads {
            let proposer = basic_authorship::ProposerFactory {
                client: service.client(),
                transaction_pool: service.transaction_pool(),
            };

            consensus_pow::start_mine(
                Box::new(service.client().clone()),
                service.client(),
                kulupu_pow::RandomXAlgorithm::new(service.client()),
                proposer,
                None,
                round,
                service.network(),
                std::time::Duration::new(2, 0),
                service.select_chain().map(|v| v.clone()),
                inherent_data_providers.clone(),
            );
        }
    }

    Ok(service)
}
```

In this case, you just need to start your node with the `--validator` flag and an `--author` flag with address:

```sh
cargo run --release -- --validator --author 0x7e946b7dd192307b4538d664ead95474062ac3738e04b5f3084998b76bc5122d
```

Comment: yes,that's awesome,but I don't want the mining process in the runtime or in the node.I want the miner to mining and then send the mining info to node through rpc. Could you share your idea?

Comment: The PoW module doesn't support that at the moment - we indeed need to have RPC methods `getWork` and `submitWork` so that people can implement mining pools, but for now you will have to implement these yourself.